# How to run puppeteer on AWS Fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, puppeteer, docker-container, aws-fargate

I have integrated my GUI with puppeteer. It runs fine locally. I want to deploy my application on AWS.

After deploying UI on AWS Fargate, I get the following error message:
[image]

How can I resolve this error?
The error means that chromium is not found on docker container. Right?
I have given the command to download chromium in my docker file. While installing packages, it downloads the browser as well. Still it throws this error when container runs.

Kindly suggest a way to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

First, check the path of chromium-browser, and if it work on local it should on Fargate, how you start the container locally? verify the local path of the chromium and add that path in the task definition of Fargate, as the current path does not seems correct.

You can add ENV to [task definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html).

```
"environment" : [
    { "name" : "CHROMIUM_PATH", "value" : "/usr/bin/chromium-browser" }
]
```